# USB headset is shown as disabled in Audio Hardware

Tags: usb, sound, soundcard

I'm having a peculiar problem with my USB headset.  Sometimes it works fine, but many other times it doesn't. The headset is recognised correctly:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                      HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf7e34000 irq 46
 1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7e30000 irq 45
 2 [C320M          ]: USB-Audio - Plantronics C320-M
                      Plantronics Plantronics C320-M at usb-0000:00:14.0-1.1, full speed
```

The last one is the headset.

Yet, in the hardware tab of the sound options, it's listed correctly but says "Disabled":

[image]

Obviously, as it's disabled, I can't select it as output or input device. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the only way to make it work was to disable ALL sound cards by setting them to OFF , restart the computer and then enable the headset first.

It worked then.